# Passing argument to nrpe

Tags: nagios, nrpe

**Remote hosts nrpe.conf**

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_users -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

**Monitoring host:**

```
define command{
        command_name check_nrpe
        command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a $ARG2$
       }

define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        hostgroup_name                  linux-servers
        service_description             Current Users
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_users!15!20
}
```

I getting usage error with this configuration , please help

Answer (score 1):

Change `check_nrpe!check_users!15!20` to `check_nrpe!check_users!"15 20"`.

With your current config, as far as Nagios is concerned:

```
ARG1 = check_users
ARG2 = 15
ARG3 = 20
```

But then your command only uses `ARG1` and `ARG2`, so the `20` isn't passed to NRPE.

You want ARG2 to be `"15 20"`, which NRPE will then split into two ARGs on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the actual values as thresholds in **nrpe.cfg/nrpe.conf** on remote host in place of $ARG1$ and $ARG2$.

Eg : **command[check_users]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_users -w 15 -c 20**

Along with this just to be sure, do check if :

1. **Check_Users** command defined properly in **commands.cfg** on monitoring host.
2. check if path of plugin(check_users) used in config files is correct and permissions are setup properly.

Rest seems to be fine and if above doesn't work, then paste the actual error.